# Do OpenCV's machine learning algorithms continuously update a model?

Tags: c++, opencv

Most machine learning algorithms implemented in OpenCV 2.4 built upon a `CvStatModel` which comes with a [CvStatModel::train](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/ml/doc/statistical_models.html#bool%20CvStatModel::train(const%20Mat&%20train_data,%20[int%20tflag,]%20...,%20const%20Mat&%20responses,%20...,%20[const%20Mat&%20var_idx,]%20...,%20[const%20Mat&%20sample_idx,]%20...%20[const%20Mat&%20var_type,]%20...,%20[const%20Mat&%20missing_mask,]%20%3Cmisc_training_alg_params%3E%20...)) method.

There it says:

> By default, the input feature vectors are stored as train_data rows, that is, all the components (features) of a training vector are stored continuously.

and

> Usually, the previous model state is cleared by CvStatModel::clear() before running the training procedure. However, some algorithms may optionally update the model state with the new training data, instead of resetting it.

How do I know which ml algorithm isn't resetting the current model state. Since I wanted to use [CvGBTrees::train](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/ml/doc/gradient_boosted_trees.html#bool%20CvGBTrees::train(const%20Mat&%20trainData,%20int%20tflag,%20const%20Mat&%20responses,%20const%20Mat&%20varIdx,%20const%20Mat&%20sampleIdx,%20const%20Mat&%20varType,%20const%20Mat&%20missingDataMask,%20CvGBTreesParams%20params,%20bool%20update)) which has a `update` parameter declared as being only a dummy parameter, I guess the model is discarded after every training call. Can I take it that if there is no such update parameter the current model state will always be discarded?

I need a machine learning algorithm which continuously trains one model and doesn't start with an initial model every training call.

Is this doable with the current ml implementations in OpenCV? and if so with which ones? Furthermore, if not are there other c++ libraries that would do so?